# Why isn't to_char IMMUTABLE, and how can I work around it?

Tags: postgresql, index, string-representation

How can I index a `to_char()` of a column?

I have tried:

```
adam_db=> CREATE INDEX updates_hourly_idx 
          ON updates (to_char(update_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00'));
```

But got the error:

> ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked `IMMUTABLE`

Which seems strange, since the `to_char()` of a timestamp is reasonably immutable.

Any ideas how to generate that index?

Comment: I would've expected `to_char` of a `timestamp` to be immutable, yes. Not for `timestamptz`, but that's not what you're using. However, `\df+ to_char` shows all the `to_char` variants are only `stable`.

Comment: Can you add a new column to the table? If so, you could update that column to contain the function output and index it.

Comment: The interesting question about the not immutable character of `to_char()` aside (Daniel nailed it) - may I inquire the purpose of such index? My educated guess is you do not need it. Rather cast search expressions to `timestamp` and use a plain index on the timestamp column, or if you need values truncated to full hours, use [`date_trunc('hour', update_time)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) instead, which is immutable for `timestamp` (but not for `timestamptz`, obviously).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formats accepted by `to_char(timestamp, text)` include localized patterns that make it not immutable.

Example of different results with the same input:

```
test=> BEGIN;
test=> set lc_time='en_US.utf8';
test=> select to_char(now()::timestamp, 'TMDay');
 to_char 
---------
 Monday

test=> set lc_time TO 'fr_FR.utf8';
test=> select to_char(now()::timestamp, 'TMDay');
 to_char 
---------
 Lundi

test=> END;
```

If not using this kind of format, the solution is to create your own immutable wrapper function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION custom_to_char(timestamp) RETURNS text AS
$$ select to_char($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00'); $$
LANGUAGE sql immutable;
```

and then create the index on that function.

Answer (score 3):

I just found another solution to this problem based on [this forum post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/dcc563d10912241656t61c23a63s1c4c7de71e67facf@mail.gmail.com) -- `EXTRACT(timestamp with time zone)` isn't immutable, but `EXTRACT(timestamp)` **is**. So it is possible to create a table with `CREATE INDEX ON table (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))`.