# Can declaring function volatility IMMUTABLE harm performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance, functions

Postgres functions are declared with [volatility classification `VOLATILE`, `STABLE` or `IMMUTABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html). The project is known to be very strict with these labels for built-in functions. And with good reason. Prominent example: expression indexes only allow `IMMUTABLE` functions and those have to be truly immutable to avoid incorrect results.

**User-defined functions** are still free to be declared as the owner chooses. [The manual advises:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html)

> For best optimization results, you should label your functions with the strictest volatility category that is valid for them.

... and adds an extensive list of things that can go wrong with an incorrect volatility label.

Still, there are cases where faking immutability makes sense. Mostly when you *know* the function is, in fact, immutable within your scope. Example:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

All possible **implications on data integrity aside**, what is the effect on performance? [One might assume](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/209796/3684) declaring a function `IMMUTABLE` can only be beneficial to **performance** . Is that so?

**Can declaring function volatility `IMMUTABLE` *harm* performance?**

Let's assume current Postgres 10 to narrow it down, but all recent versions are of interest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it ***can*** harm performance.

Simple SQL functions can be **"inlined"** in the calling query. [Quoting the Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions):

> SQL functions (i.e. `LANGUAGE SQL`) will, under certain conditions, have
> their function bodies inlined into the calling query rather than being
> invoked directly. This can have **substantial performance advantages**
> since the function body becomes exposed to the planner of the calling
> query, which can apply optimizations such as constant-folding, qual
> pushdown, and so on.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

To enforce correctness, there are a number of preconditions. [One of them](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions):

> if the function is declared `IMMUTABLE`, then the expression must not invoke any non-immutable function or operator

Meaning, SQL functions using any non-immutable functions but still being declared `IMMTUTABLE` are excluded from this optimization. Triggered by these related answers on SO, I have been running extensive tests:

- [How to aggregate data from multiple years on MM-DD, ignoring year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376115/939860)
- [How do you do date math that ignores the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15179731/939860)

Basically comparing these two variants of a simple SQL function (mapping dates to an `integer`, ignoring the year which doesn't matter for the purpose):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_mmdd_tc_s(date)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE    AS
$$SELECT to_char($1, 'MMDD')::int$$;

CREATE FUNCTION f_mmdd_tc_i(date)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT to_char($1, 'MMDD')::int$$;  -- cannot be inlined!
```

The Postgres function `to_char()` is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE` (all overloaded instances of it - [for reasons beyond the scope of this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77301/3684)). So the second one is **fake `IMMUTABLE` and turns out to be 5x slower** in a simple test:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0e86aabb2a235b3d415720107fe0a35c)*

***This specific example*** can be replaced with the equivalent:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_mmdd(date)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT (EXTRACT(month FROM $1) * 100 + EXTRACT(day FROM $1))::int';
```

Would *seem* more expensive with two function calls and more computations. But the `IMMUTABLE` label is ***true*** (plus, the used function is faster and coercing `text` to `integer` is more expensive, too). **2x as fast** as the faster variant above (10x as fast as the slower).

The point being: Use `IMMUTABLE` functions **where possible**, and think twice before you "cheat". (There are odd cases where this still makes sense.)