# How can I find out if a SQL function can be inlined?

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, execution-plan, functions

In [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212197/2639) Erwin breaks down `IMMUTABLE` functions into those that can be inlined, and those that can't. He has an example with `to_char()` that shows an `IMMUTABLE` function over `to_char()` will actually be **slower**.

That's interesting though because I didn't even know `to_char()` wasn't `IMMUTABLE`. Moreover, I didn't know that `IMMUTABLE` would ever make anything slower. My question is now, how do I find out if a function marked as `IMMUTABLE` is being inlined, or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It changes the actual execution plan, so you can tell from the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE)`. Example:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE) SELECT my_func(col) FROM tbl;
```

I simplified and adapted the fiddle from my previous [answer that you are referring to](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212197/3684):

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sA_4pviG)

The first function is inlined, hence you see the inlined expression in the output:

> ```
> Output: (to_char((d)::timestamp with time zone, 'MMDD'::text))::integer
> ```

The second function is not inlined, hence you see the function call in the output:

> ```
> Output: f_mmdd_tc_i(d)
> ```

To be precise: this shows whether the function has been inlined in the tested query. If it has *not*, that does not necessarily prove it *can't* be (under different circumstances).
And the test is not bound to just `IMMUTABLE` functions in any way.