# Containment check tstzrange @> timestamptz not using btree or gist index

Tags: postgresql, index, btree, gist-index, postgresql-11

Schema:

```
        Column        |           Type           
----------------------+--------------------------
 id                   | integer                  
 event_id             | integer                  
 started_at           | timestamp with time zone 
 ended_at             | timestamp with time zone 
 created_at           | timestamp with time zone 
    "event_seat_state_lookup_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "event_seating_lookup_created_at_idx" btree (created_at)
    "event_seating_lookup_created_at_idx2" gist (created_at)
```

Query:

```
SELECT id
FROM event_seating_lookup esl1
WHERE
  tstzrange(now() - interval '1 hour', now() + interval '1 hour', '[)') @> esl1.created_at;
```

Explain analyze:

Table with <100k rows.

```
 Seq Scan on event_seating_lookup esl1  (cost=0.00..1550.30 rows=148 width=4) (actual time=0.013..19.956 rows=29103 loops=1)
   Filter: (tstzrange((now() - '01:00:00'::interval), (now() + '01:00:00'::interval), '[)'::text) @> created_at)
   Buffers: shared hit=809
 Planning Time: 0.110 ms
 Execution Time: 21.942 ms
```

Table with 1M+ rows:

```
Seq Scan on event_seating_lookup esl1  (cost=10000000000.00..10000042152.75 rows=5832 width=4) (actual time=0.009..621.895 rows=1166413 loops=1)
  Filter: (tstzrange((now() - '01:00:00'::interval), (now() + '01:00:00'::interval), '[)'::text) @> created_at)
  Buffers: shared hit=12995
Planning Time: 0.092 ms
Execution Time: 697.927 ms
```

I have tried:

```
VACUUM FULL event_seating_lookup;
VACUUM event_seating_lookup;
VACUUM ANALYZE event_seating_lookup;
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Problem:

`event_seating_lookup_created_at_idx` or `event_seating_lookup_created_at_idx2` indexes are not being used.

Notes:

- PostgreSQL 11.1.
- `btree_gist` extension is installed.
- I have tried equivalent setup with `created_at timestamp without time zone` and using `tsrange`; same result.
- I understand that rewriting the query with `>=`, `<` checks would make it use the btree index. The question is what is the reason the index is not used with the `tstzrange` containment operator and if there is a way to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

> The question is what is the reason the index is not used with the `tstzrange` containment operator and if there is a way to make it work.

The ***reason*** is quite trivial. B-tree indexes do no support the containment operator `@>`. Neither for [range types like `tstzrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) nor for any other type (including array types).

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-behavior.html)

> ... a btree operator class must provide five comparison operators, `<`, `<=`,
>   `=`, `>=` and `>`.

And GiST indexes do not support `<`, `<=`, > `=`, `>=` and `>`. See these chapters of the manual:

- [Built-in Operator Classes for GiST indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-builtin-opclasses.html)
- [Behavior of B-Tree Operator Classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-behavior.html)

In Postgres indexes are bound to operators (which are implemented for certain types), not data types alone or functions or anything else. Related:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)
- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

The GiST index `event_seating_lookup_created_at_idx2` you have is **pointless**. It is created on the `timestamptz` column `created_at`. Such a GiST index would be useful for a *range* type (the opposite direction of logic).

Creating a GiST index on a `timestamptz` column is only possible since you installed the additional `btree_gist` extension to allow such useless indexes. (There are useful applications for multicolumn indexes or exclusion constraints ...) In stock Postgres you'd get an error:

> ERROR: data type timestamp with time zone has no default operator class for access method "gist"

So while it's logically valid and technically possible to use a btree index (or a GiST index) for the query, the case is not implemented: **no index support for `timestamptz <@ tstzrange`** (where `timestamptz` would be the indexed expression!). It can be solved with `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` more efficiently. So I guess no developer felt (or will feel) the need to implement it.

#### Function to rewrite expression with favorable operators

[Your implementation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/226921/3684) makes sense to me. It does what you want and due to [function inlining](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) makes use of a plain btree index on the timestamp column - `event_seating_lookup_created_at_idx` in your example. For calls with a **constant range** (like in a single function call) I suggest this modified version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION in_range(timestamptz, tstzrange)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN lower_inc($2) THEN $1 >= lower($2) ELSE $1 > lower($2) END
   AND CASE WHEN upper_inc($2) THEN $1 <= upper($2) ELSE $1 < upper($2) END
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Declare it `IMMUTABLE`, because it actually is. Not to help function inlining (can even prevent it if the declaration is false) but for other gains. Related:

- [Can declaring function volatility IMMUTABLE harm performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212195/can-declaring-function-volatility-immutable-harm-performance/212197#212197)
- [PostgreSQL Inline Function Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040170/postgresql-inline-function-behavior/53040824#53040824)

It can be inlined and uses the index just like your version. The difference: this one suppresses a redundant index condition for exclusive bounds. Fortunately, your consideration in this regard is slightly off target:

> The reason for first matching on `the $1 >= lower($2) AND $1 <= upper($2)`
>   condition and then checking the `upper_inc` and `lower_inc`
>   constraints is to benefit from range scan first and then filter the result.

Postgres 11 (at least) is even smarter than that. I see no `Filter` step for your version. For default `[)` bounds (like in your example), I get this query plan (line breaks in conditions added by me):

```
  ->  Index Only Scan using foo_idx on foo (actual rows=5206 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((datetime >= '2018-09-05 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                 AND (datetime <= '2018-09-05 22:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                 AND (datetime < '2018-09-05 22:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
```

An actual `Filter` step could add a more substantial cost for corner cases with many hits on an excluded bound. Those would be fetched from the index and then discarded. Quite relevant for time ranges where values often end up on bounds - like timestamps on the full hour.

The actual difference is see is minor, but why not take it?

```
  ->  Index Only Scan using foo_idx on foo (actual rows=5206 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((datetime >= '2018-09-05 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                 AND (datetime < '2018-09-05 22:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as my research goes, [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) is not able to rewrite containment check into an expression that could be matched using btree index, i.e.

```
esl1.created_at >= now() - interval '1 hour' AND
esl1.created_at < now() + interval '1 hour'
```

when written such way, the query is executed using indexes:

```
Index Scan using event_seating_lookup_created_at_idx on event_seating_lookup esl1  (cost=0.44..12623.56 rows=18084 width=4) (actual time=0.013..57.084 rows=70149 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((created_at >= (now() - '01:00:00'::interval)) AND (created_at < (now() + '01:00:00'::interval)))
Planning Time: 0.223 ms
Execution Time: 62.209 ms
```

As I prefer syntax of the containment query over the latter form, I researched possible alternatives. What came up is that I can write a procedure that will inline the condition for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION in_range(timestamptz, tstzrange)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
SELECT
  (
    $1 >= lower($2) AND
    $1 <= upper($2) AND
    (
      upper_inc($2) OR
      $1 < upper($2)
    ) AND
    (
      lower_inc($2) OR
      $1 > lower($2)
    )
  )
$$
language sql;
```

The reason for first matching on the `$1 >= lower($2) AND $1 <= upper($2)` condition and then checking the `upper_inc` and `lower_inc` constraints is to benefit from range scan first and then filter the result.

Comment: This is similar to what PostGis does (example function [`ST_DWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)): rewrite functions with the right operators to target certain indexes. So the general approach can make sense. Just make sure the function can be inlined. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212199/3684. And declare it `IMMUTABLE` since it is. (Not sure about your handling of bounds ...)

Comment: Regarding `immutable` attribute. Thats what I did at first, but then I got feedback saying that "you should usually avoid declaring inlinable _scalar_ sql funcs as immutable. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions read it; declaring an sql function immutable can only make it _less_ inlinable. for scalar functions, that is; and once the function is inlined, what matters for const-simplification is the operators and functions inside the body, which are not affected by an "immutable" declaration on the function itself"

Comment: While the feedback you got is true, it is also *not applicable* to your case. Since everything in the function body is immutable (incl. `upper()`, `upper_inc()`, `lower()`, `lower_inc()` -  I checked!) you should declare it as such. That's not to help inlining, but it allows various other optimizations.

Comment: I added an alternative version of your smart function to my answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter 'RhodiumToad> gajus: I don't do stackexchange, but feel free to respond to the [Erwin Brandstetter] pointing out that your advice came from a postgresql developer, and that he can learn why he's wrong by coming to the irc channel [#postgresql on Freenode]'

Comment: Gladly. wrong about what?