# PostgreSQL functions inside where clause

Tags: postgresql, functions

I have table like this:

```
table a (
   id 
   --
   p1 text,
   p2 text,
   p3 text
)
```

When I write some function, which use this table, I need to write code like this

```
create or replace function ...

select * from a
   where a.p1 is not null
     and a.p2 is not null
     and a.p3 is not null
```

I want to create a function,

```
 create function my_function(??? val) returns boolean as -- what I need to place instead of ???
 $$
 begin
     return val.p1 is not null 
        and val.p2 is not null
        and val.p3 is not null;
 end;
 $$ language plpgsql
```

in which I will pass "this" instance of current row (I don't know, how it called) and my functions will be like this:

```
select * from a
   where my_function(???) -- what I need to place instead of ???
```

My questions are:

1. Can I create function `my_function` like above?
2. If point 1 is true, what type I need to write for parameter? And what I need write on `where` clause?

Comment: If the question would declare the Postgres version(s) it is for, I would upvote. (`SELECT version()` helps.) Because it's a good question otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every table that is created a type with the same name is created. So you you can define your function to accept the table's type.

Such a function is also better written as a SQL function to avoid the overhead of PL/pgSQL.

```
create function my_function(val a) returns boolean as 
 $$
 select val.p1 is not null 
    and val.p2 is not null
    and val.p3 is not null;
 $$ 
 language sql
 stable;
```

The **`a`** in `(val a)` is the name of your table.

You can use that function in the following way:

```
select * 
from a
where my_function(a);
```

Comment: decorating the function with stable may prevent inlining in some circumstances, reducing possible optimisation.

Comment: @Jasen: hmm, I thought this was a minimum for being able to be inlined. Would a `volatile` ever be inlined? [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) claims that: "*For best optimization results, you should label your functions with the strictest volatility category that is valid for them*"

Comment: I think LANGUAGE SQL functions are a special case, I'll go look at the documentation and report back.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions : it seems that `stable` does not prevent inlining unless it is a lie

Comment: @Jasen: Actually, the function can and should be `IMMUTABLE` since the body is all-immutable. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212195/can-declaring-function-volatility-immutable-harm-performance