# Very bad query plan in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.6, statistics

I have a performance problem with PostgreSQL 9.6.17 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit). Sometimes very inefficient query plan is chosen for relatively simple query.

There is `dir_current` table with 750M rows:

`\d sf.dir_current`

```
                                         Table "sf.dir_current"
       Column       |    Type     | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
--------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 id                 | bigint      |           | not null | nextval('sf.object_id_seq'::regclass)
 volume_id          | bigint      |           | not null |
 parent_id          | bigint      |           |          |
 blocks             | sf.blkcnt_t |           |          |
 rec_aggrs          | jsonb       |           | not null |
...
Indexes:
    "dir_current_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id), tablespace "sf_current"
    "dir_current_parentid_idx" btree (parent_id), tablespace "sf_current"
    "dir_current_volumeid_id_unq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (volume_id, id), tablespace "sf_current"
Foreign-key constraints:
    "dir_current_parentid_fk" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES sf.dir_current(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

(some columns omitted as they're irrelevant here).

Now, a temporary table is created with ca. 1K rows:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE dir_process AS (
  SELECT sf.dir_current.id, volume_id, parent_id, depth, size, blocks, atime, ctime, mtime, sync_time, local_aggrs FROM sf.dir_current
  WHERE ....
);
CREATE INDEX dir_process_indx ON dir_process(volume_id, id);
ANALYZE dir_process;
```

The actual condition `....` doesn't matter here - it selects some rows to be processed.

Here is a query which is sometimes very slow:

```
SELECT dir.id, dir.volume_id, dir.parent_id, dir.rec_aggrs, dir.blocks
FROM sf.dir_current AS dir
INNER JOIN dir_process ON dir.parent_id = dir_process.id 
                      AND dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id
WHERE dir.volume_id = ANY($volume_ids);  -- $volume_ids = manual input
```

This query is run thousands of times a day and only a few (say 5 a day) result in an inefficient query.

I can't post `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` as this issue occurs only sometimes so I need to depend on the logs. A few slow plans:

```
duration: 1822060.789 ms  plan:
Merge Join  (cost=150260.47..265775.37 rows=1 width=456) (actual rows=14305 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id)
  Join Filter: (dir.parent_id = dir_process.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 23117117695
  ->  Index Scan using dir_current_volumeid_id_unq on dir_current dir  (cost=0.12..922747.05 rows=624805 width=456) (actual rows=1231600 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (volume_id = ANY ('{88}'::bigint[]))
  ->  Sort  (cost=966.16..975.55 rows=18770 width=16) (actual rows=23115900401 loops=1)
        Sort Key: dir_process.volume_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1648kB
        ->  Seq Scan on dir_process  (cost=0.00..699.70 rows=18770 width=16) (actual rows=18770 loops=1)
```

```
duration: 10140968.829 ms  plan:
Merge Join  (cost=0.17..8389.13 rows=1 width=456) (actual rows=819 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (dir_process.volume_id = dir.volume_id)
  Join Filter: (dir.parent_id = dir_process.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2153506735
  ->  Index Only Scan using dir_process_indx on dir_process  (cost=0.06..659.76 rows=1166 width=16) (actual rows=1166 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 1166
  ->  Index Scan using dir_current_volumeid_id_unq on dir_current dir  (cost=0.12..885276.20 rows=602172 width=456) (actual rows=2153506389 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (volume_id = ANY ('{5}'::bigint[]))
```

```
duration: 12524111.200 ms  plan:
Merge Join  (cost=480671.74..878819.79 rows=1 width=456) (actual rows=62 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id)
  Join Filter: (dir.parent_id = dir_process.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 153595373018
  ->  Index Scan using dir_current_volumeid_id_unq on dir_current dir  (cost=0.12..922747.05 rows=624805 width=456) (actual rows=2360101 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (volume_id = ANY ('{441}'::bigint[]))
  ->  Sort  (cost=2621.42..2653.96 rows=65080 width=16) (actual rows=153593012980 loops=1)
        Sort Key: dir_process.volume_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 4587kB
        ->  Seq Scan on dir_process  (cost=0.00..1580.80 rows=65080 width=16) (actual rows=65080 loops=1)
```

The first reaction is as usual: "do I have up to date statistics?". The answer is yes: `dir_current` is changed frequently but is also analyzed ca. once an hour. `dir_process` is analyzed as soon as it's created.
Note that estimated number of rows matches pretty well:

- est. 624805, actual=1231600
- est. 624805, actual=2360101

Where the estimates are way off is the inner loop of merge join which actually shows the number of rows times the number of loops (153593012980 or 2153506389 or 23115900401). Poor executor is spinning in the inner loop, iterating over all rows with a given `volume_id`, looking for a given `id`.

The biggest problem seems to be that Postgres chooses to do a merge join on a very inefficient condition: `dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id` instead of `dir.parent_id = dir_process.id`. For a given `volume_id` there is a few million rows in `dir_current`, for a given `parent_id` there is hundreds or thousands of rows, but not millions.
The other effective query plan is a nested loop, where outer loop is iterating over `dir_process` and using an index to fetch the row from `dir_current`.

I understand that I could disable merge join before running this query but I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Any more idea about what can be done to avoid this inefficient plan? How is it possible that it's chosen over nested loops?

I don't have control over Postgres version, unfortunately.

Comment: I took the liberty to add this comment `-- $volume_ids = manual input`. Is it correct? Please fix if not.

Comment: "I can't post explain (analyze, buffers, format text) as this issue occurs only sometimes so I need to depend on the logs"  auto_explain can be (and almost always should be, if you are using analyze in the fist place which it looks like you are) configured to record buffers.

Comment: @jjanes Do you think buffers would be make any difference here? My intuition is that no amount of PG tuning in terms of memory / I/O when the query plan is clearly bad and involves reading hundreds of millions or billions of tuples when it'd suffice to read thousands.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, you could assume that volume ids are given from outside.

Comment: No, I don't think buffers would make a difference here, it is just good practice to collect it as it can be hard to go back and find it later.

Comment: Are the bad plan always when the =ANY just has one entry in the array?  If it were written as a simple =, would that fix the problem?

Comment: Sometimes there is more than one, so it's not easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

#### Statistic for the query planner: `n_distinct`

You *do* run `ANALYZE` on the temporary table. You commented:

> The temp table is immutable: it's created once, analyzed and never
> changes. It exists because we had a problem with plain query being
> inefficient, so we extracted the rows we're interested in to a temp
> table to have statistics about it. Then the second query is used to
> find rows from `dir_current` which are children of those interesting
> ones (i.e. `dir_current.parent_id=dir_process.id`)
>
> `dir_current` is analyzed and statistics are set according to our
> experience (i.e. there is 10 rows on average with a given `parent_id`
> so `n_distinct` is set to -0.1). Given `volume_id` OTOH has millions of rows.

But how do you do that ***exactly***?

Firstly, the rows in `dir_process` are the *parents* of the rows in `dir_current` (`dir_current.parent_id = dir_process.id`). The column relevant to your query is `dir_process.id`, not `parent_id`. Setting `n_distinct` for `dir_process.parent_id` does nothing for this query. Setting it for `dir_process.id` would be wrong (`n_distinct` is actually -1, i.e. all distinct). So that's either useless or wrong.

Secondly, if done exactly like you described it (`dir_current is analyzed and statistics are set`) then nothing is achieved. `ALTER TABLE` saves the information in `pg_attribute.attoptions`. Only the next `ANALYZE` copies it to `pg_statistic`, which is actually consulted for query planning. Run `ANALYZE` ***after*** `ALTER TABLE`! Demo:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=66974db4564e1f456f0f5ab35ae71c99)*

Finally, the temp table is immutable and comparatively small. I see `rows=18770` and `rows=65080` for seq scan on `dir_process` in the plans. If that small table is reused many times it should pay to use *actual* counts instead of an estimate taken from the big table (ignoring that said statistic does not seem to apply to begin with). The actual data distribution in a small sample may be dramatically different.
**If** you set `n_distinct` explicitly, use the actual distinct count for the current selection. Something like:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE dir_process ALTER COLUMN volume_id SET (n_distinct=%s)'
             , (SELECT count(DISTINCT volume_id) FROM dir_process));
END
$$;
```

But not for `dir_process.id`. You might set that to `-1` if you don't make the column `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`.

The [manual about `n_distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html):

> If greater than zero, the estimated number of distinct values in the
> column. If less than zero, the negative of the number of distinct
> values divided by the number of rows. (The negated form is used when
> `ANALYZE` believes that the number of distinct values is likely to
> increase as the table grows; the positive form is used when the column
> seems to have a fixed number of possible values.) For example, `-1`
> indicates a unique column in which the number of distinct values is
> the same as the number of rows.

Related:

- [Postgres sometimes uses inferior index for WHERE a IN (...) ORDER BY b LIMIT N](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249617/postgres-sometimes-uses-inferior-index-for-where-a-in-order-by-b-limit-n)
- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/are-regular-vacuum-analyze-still-recommended-under-9-1/18694#18694)

#### Query

That aside, your query only retrieves columns from the main table. *Assuming* that the the temp table `dir_process` has no duplicates on `(volume_id, id)`, an `EXISTS` semi-join is equivalent, and the predicate `volume_id = ANY(volume_ids)` should rather be applied to the comparatively tiny temp table (also equivalent, and statistics are up to date now!):

```
SELECT c.id, c.volume_id, c.parent_id, c.rec_aggrs, c.blocks
FROM   sf.dir_current c
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM dir_process p
   WHERE  p.volume_id = ANY($volume_ids)
   AND    p.id = c.parent_id
   AND    p.volume_id = c.volume_id
   );
```

#### Index

I see a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(volume_id, id)` on the main table. Since the temp table seems to be a subset, the same constraint should apply and you can replace the index on the temp table:

```
CREATE INDEX dir_process_indx ON dir_process(volume_id, id);
```

with a `UNIQUE` constraint as well:

```
ALTER TABLE dir_process ADD CONSTRAINT dir_process_volumeid_id_unq
UNIQUE (volume_id, id);
```

(Implements a unique index on `(volume_id, id)` internally.) Not sure if the Postgres 9.6 query planner is helped by it, but it can only get better.

**More importantly**, an index on `(volume_id, parent_id)` on the main table should be useful:

```
CREATE INDEX dir_current_parentid_volumeid_idx ON dir_current(parent_id, volume_id);
```

Currently there is an index on just `(parent_id)`. But I suspect there can be many rows per `parent_id`, so the above should be better. (Scratch this, if `parent_id` is mostly unique!) The new index can mostly replace your existing index `dir_current_parentid_idx` on `(parent_id)`. It's 50% bigger, that's the main downside. But you wouldn't want to maintain *two* indexes without good reason. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Also, the `UNIQUE` constraint `dir_current_volumeid_id_unq` on `(volume_id, id)` has lost its usefulness for this query now. The "unique" aspect has always been redundant, as `id` is the PK and unique on its own.

Unless it has other purposes, it might be removed or reduced to an appendix to the PK with the `INCLUDE` clause in Postgres 11 or later!

Or you might make my suggested index `dir_current_parentid_volumeid_idx` on `(volume_id, parent_id)` (switched column order) instead to replace this. (And keep the index on just `(parent_id)`, obviously.)

See:

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190132/do-covering-indexes-in-postgresql-help-join-columns/190151#190151)
- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938#207938)

Should be very fast all the time now.

Comment: [Postgres 9.6 is reaches EOL this year](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Current versions have gotten substantially better with big data (among other things). Consider upgrading ASAP. (You said you don't have control, but suggest this to whoever has.)

Comment: I understand that 13.2 is way better and we're in the process of migrating the product to 13.2 with tables partitioned over volume_id. 

However, this query smells to me like a potential bug in the PG itself - merge join using very inefficient condition. I am having hard time understanding why such a poor merge condition could be chosen by the planner.

We've seen it replicated recently when testing partitioned DB with PG 13.2 (with exactly same query) - but again it's hard to catch is it happens even more rarely.

Comment: @gozdal: If you fix up column statistics like I addressed in my first paragraph, and the problem persists, then *maybe* you are on to something. But all bets are off while you operate on outdated statistics. The rest of my post suggests a different approch that should be more efficient, regardless.

Comment: The temp table is immutable: it's created once, analyzed and never changes. It exists because we had a problem with plain query being inefficient, so we extracted the rows we're interested in to a temp table to have statistics about it.
Then the second query is used to find rows from `dir_current` which are children of those interesting ones (i.e. `dir_current.parent_id=dir_process.id`)

Comment: `dir_current` is analyzed and statistics are set according to our experience (i.e. there is 10 rows on average with a given `parent_id` so `n_distinct` is set to -0.1). Given `volume_id` OTOH has millions of rows.

Comment: @gozdal: Obviously, I had main table and temp table confused for my advise concerning `ANALYZE` and statistics. Plus, your comments made my Spidey sense tingle. So I adapted my first paragraph. A lot.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin. I've read your revised answer and it seems I have created some confusion.

Comment: `n_distinct` is set on `dir_current.parent_id` to `-0.1` whenever DB is created.
`ANALYZE` on `dir_current` are run regularly on the table.

`dir_process` is analyzed once, table is immutable and statistics on it are not altered.

Looking at the query plans I've pasted I believe the statistics themselves are doing good job at estimating:
`dir_current_volumeid_id_unq on dir_current dir  (cost=0.12..922747.05 rows=624805 width=456) (actual rows=1231600 loops=1)
`

Comment: The main problem I see is that the merge condition 
`Merge Cond: (dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id)`
will be extremely inefficient and I don't understand how it's chosen.

Had it been `Merge Cond: (dir.parent_id = dir_process.id)` then it would have made much more sense to me.

Comment: I see, more misunderstandings concerning statistics. Distracting from the more important part: `the predicate volume_id = ANY(volume_ids) should rather be applied to the comparatively tiny temp table`.

Comment: > the predicate `volume_id = ANY(volume_ids)` should rather be applied to the comparatively tiny temp table

Do you think this changes how PostgreSQL plans this query? The typical scenario is that there is a single distinct value there in the temp table.

Comment: I think it makes a difference. That's why I brought it up.