# How to select sub-object with given keys from JSONB?

Tags: postgresql, functions, json

How to extract / get / select a "sub object" from a json(b) object in Postgres?

There seems to be a lot of info that get me almost all the way there but not quite. Lots of stuff about converting to records, filtering and then building a new object out of it. TBH, I'm really surprised that this is not a builtin capability. Perhaps there's a simple way to achieve this by composing builtin fns? What I'm looking for is essentially the equivalent of [`select-keys`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys); a function (say, `jsonb_select_keys`) that given this:

```
SELECT jsonb_select_keys('{"a":42,"b":43,"c":44,"d":97}', '{a,d,e}');
```

would return this:

```
{"a":42,"d":97}
```

Kind of like `jsonb_path_query_array` but for k-v pairs instead of values.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  Are there any plans to allow for a KV JSON(B) type which enforces uniqueness of the key? There might be some benefit to that along with the ideas you explore in your answer? I mean, naturally, apart from the PK of the table itself! Thoughts?

Comment: @Vérace: Well, `jsonb` already enforces unique keys (while `json` does not). I elaborated and added a quote from the manual below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can ***remove*** given keys with the **`-`** operator (the inverse of what you have in mind). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

> `jsonb - text[]` → `jsonb`
>
> Deletes all matching keys or array elements from the left operand.
>
> `'{"a": "b", "c": "d"}'::jsonb - '{a,c}'::text[]` → `{}`

But I wouldn't know of a built-in function or operator doing what you ask (incl. the current Postgres 15).

Remarkably, it's the other way round with  SQL `SELECT` statements. There you get a positive list with `SELECT a,d,e FROM tbl`, but cannot simply get *"all columns except [a,d,e]"* like you can get *"all keys except [a,d,e]"* from a JSON object with the above operator. I would love to have the complementary feature for each.

Also can't think of an easy way with the SQL/JSON path language (Postgres 12+).

#### Workaround for `jsonb`

You can create a simple function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jsonb_select_keys(_js jsonb, _keys text[])
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(t.key, t.value)
FROM   jsonb_each(_js) t
WHERE  t.key = ANY (_keys);
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ef4454fc1bef512d21ebbafc131fcf1f)*

Call:

```
SELECT f_jsonb_select_keys('{"a":42,"b":43,"c":44,"d":97}', '{a,d,e}');
```

Returns:

```
{"a":42,"d":97}
```

You get NULL for NULL or empty input for either argument (as demonstrated in the fiddle). So I declared the function **`STRICT`** (a.k.a. `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`), even though the nested function `jsonb_object_agg()` is not `STRICT`. That *could* mess with function inlining, but since this one cannot be inlined anyway (containing an aggregate function), we might as well. See:

- [Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672967/939860)
- [Can declaring function volatility IMMUTABLE harm performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212195/can-declaring-function-volatility-immutable-harm-performance)

`IMMUTABLE` is only kind of true. Keep reading.

#### Order of keys?

`jsonb` does not preserve the order of keys (keys are ordered in deterministic fashion internally), so we need not bother about the order of input rows in the aggregation. **Except** when there can be duplicates, then the latest copy from the input prevails. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)

> Because the `json` type stores an exact copy of the input text, it
> will preserve semantically-insignificant white space between tokens,
> as well as the order of keys within JSON objects. Also, if a JSON
> object within the value contains the same key more than once, all the
> key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider the last
> value as the operative one.) By contrast, `jsonb` does not preserve
> white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not
> keep duplicate object keys. If duplicate keys are specified in the
> input, only the last value is kept.

Meaning, if there can be duplicate keys in the input, the order of rows is significant. My function does not explicitly order rows, so the result would not strictly be `IMMUTABLE`. But the input comes directly from `jsonb_each()` and there cannot be duplicate keys in `jsonb` (unlike `json`). Possible duplicates in the input array of keys are irrelevant for the `= ANY` construct. So duplicates can never happen. `IMMUTABLE` after all.

Again, this would prohibit function inlining - if it could be inlined to begin with.

#### Equivalent for `json`

For completeness: the same **for `json` instead of `jsonb`**:

The first variant does *not* try to preserve the given order of keys, and it eliminates possible duplicates in the input array of keys (but not possible duplicates from the `json` input!):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_json_select_keys(_js json, _keys text[])
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT json_object_agg (t.key, t.value)
FROM   json_each(_js) t
WHERE  key = ANY (_keys);
$func$;
```

The second variant preserves the given order of keys and keeps all possible duplicates. (If the same key is 2x in the `json` input, and 3x in the input array of keys, you get it 6x in the result.):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_json_select_keys(_js json, _keys text[])
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT json_object_agg (t.key, t.value ORDER BY ord)
FROM   unnest(_keys) WITH ORDINALITY k(key, ord)
JOIN   json_each(_js) t USING (key);
$func$;
```

About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)

I made the `json` functions `STABLE` because `json_object_agg()` is only `STABLE` as opposed to `jsonb_object_agg()`, which is `IMMUTABLE`.

---

You *could* use `json_build_object ('a', js->'a', 'd', js->'d', 'e', js->'e')` but that would include all keys, with a NULL value if not found. Not exactly your request. And you couldn't tell the difference between a missing key and the same key with an actual NULL value.

Comment: Thank you Erwin for the extended answer. This is almost the same as I ended up solving this (your solution is cleaner and I will use it instead!) And, thanks for turning my attention to new keywords I did not know existed in pg: `IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE`.

Comment: @AlexanderF: All of these keywords should only be used when they really apply

Comment: @AlexanderF: I added variants for `json` and elaborated on point on said keywords. Tricky details.