# Is this function PARALLEL SAFE?

Tags: postgresql, functions, parallelism

Looking at the function `f_jsonb_select_keys` from this answer:
[How to select sub-object with given keys from JSONB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290005/how-to-select-sub-object-with-given-keys-from-jsonb/290029#290029)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

> Aggregate functions that support Partial Mode are eligible to
> participate in various optimizations, such as parallel aggregation.

In here, **jsonb_object_agg** partial node is **NO**
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/parallel-safety.html

> In general, if a function is labeled as being safe when it is
> restricted or unsafe, or if it is labeled as being restricted when it
> is in fact unsafe, it may throw errors or produce wrong answers when
> used in a parallel query. C-language functions could in theory exhibit
> totally undefined behavior if mislabeled, since there is no way for
> the system to protect itself against arbitrary C code, but in most
> likely cases the result will be no worse than for any other function.
> If in doubt, it is probably best to label functions as UNSAFE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jsonb_select_keys(_js jsonb, _keys text[])
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(t.key, t.value)
FROM   jsonb_each(_js) t
WHERE  t.key = ANY (_keys);
$func$;
```

- `jsonb_each` is parallel safe, but from the above excerpt from manual, `jsonb_object_agg` is parallel unsafe?
- Overall, is the function `f_jsonb_select_keys` parallel safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Partial mode" is not required for a function to be `PARALLEL SAFE`. All involved functions are parallel safe, so my custom function can safely be marked `PARALLEL SAFE`, as well.

```
test=> SELECT proname, proparallel
test-> FROM   pg_proc
test-> WHERE  proname IN ('jsonb_object_agg', 'jsonb_each', 'json_object_agg', 'json_each');
     proname      | proparallel 
------------------+-------------
 json_each        | s
 json_object_agg  | s
 jsonb_each       | s
 jsonb_object_agg | s
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html)

> `proparallel` `char`
>
> `proparallel` tells whether the function can be safely run in parallel
> mode. It is `s` for functions which are safe to run in parallel mode
> without restriction.

Also, think about it: if `f_jsonb_select_keys()` is used in a query and the planner uses multiple worker processes, the nested `jsonb_object_agg()` only ever aggregates the output of its "own" `jsonb_each()`, there is no overlap with other processes. Nothing that could mess with parallelism.