# What is meant by a non-volatile expression in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Reading [this post](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/add-new-table-column-default-value-postgresql-11/), the author references a "non-volatile" expression, after researching a bit, I'm still not sure what it is. What is meant by a non-volatile expression in Postgresql?

Comment: A trip to the [docco](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/xfunc-volatility.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"**Immutable**" expressions resolve to the same value *always*. Like `2 + 3`.

"**Stable**" expressions resolve to the same value within a single table scan. Like: `now()`.

"**Volatile**" expressions can resolve to a different value for each evaluation. Like: `clock_timestamp()`.

"Non-volatile" would be in one of the first two categories.

Related:

- [Can declaring function volatility IMMUTABLE harm performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212195/can-declaring-function-volatility-immutable-harm-performance)
- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behavior of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573737/939860)